# Colour laser printer

Tags: printer, led

I am looking for a colour LED or Laser printer for home use.

Important:

- Reasonable photo quality (I understand lasers don't have great performance here, but for instance one of the Brother LED printers gets reasonable critique).
- Duplex printing.
- WiFi.
- £200 or less.

Nice:

- Scanner would be nice, does not have to have automatic feed (ADF).
- LED rather than a laser printer would be ideal, but not essential.
- Ideally not too large.
- Printing from mobile supported (via WiFi).

I like the [Brother DCP-9020CDW](http://www.trustedreviews.com/brother-dcp-9020cdw-review) [(also here)](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/printers/53022/brother-dcp-9020cdw-review) or its [little "Brother"](http://www.itpro.co.uk/laser-printers/26105/brother-dcp-9015cdw-review) (I'm assuming the only difference is the ADF?), but they are somewhat big and heavy (~20kg!). Any ideas? Thank you.